# Problem with a simple calculator program where an error always seems to occur when entering the number zero

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm new to the stack overflow website, python, and programming as a whole. So pardon me if the title or body of this question isn't apt.

I'm trying to create a simple calculator program in python, which performs only four operations, namely, addition, subtraction (difference), multiplication and division.

Here's my code:

```
print("Welcome to the calculator \n")

num1 = int(input("Enter the first number \n"))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number \n"))

operation = (input("""Enter the symbol of the operation to be performed. Your choices are:
                                             +
                                             - (Difference)
                                             *
                                             /
\n """))

add = num1+num2

sub1 = num1-num2
sub2 = num2 - num1

product = num1*num2
quotient = num1 / num2


if operation == "-" :

    if num1 > num2:
        print(sub1)
    else:
        print(sub2)

elif operation == "+" :
    print(add)

elif operation == "*" :
    print(product)

elif operation == "/" :
    if num2 == 0:
        print("Sorry, can't divide a number by zero")
    else:
        print(quotient)

else:
    print("Please enter a valid operator from among the ones provided above")
```

Everything runs fine, except, when I enter zero as num2, and no matter what operator I select, the output
is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py.txt", line 19, in <module>
    quotient = num1 / num2
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Its an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new, I will explain this in more detail so you actually know what you are doing wrong

Pay attention to these lines

```
add = num1+num2

sub1 = num1-num2
sub2 = num2 - num1

product = num1*num2
quotient = num1 / num2
```

When you do this it is actually performing the calculation and assigning it to the respective value (i.e. quotient = num1 / num2 will actually do the calculation and store the result in the quotient variable). So, you are doing every calculation every time regardless of your choice of operator. It would be better to assign the values only if that operator has been chosen like below.

```
print("Welcome to the calculator \n")

num1 = int(input("Enter the first number \n"))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number \n"))

operation = (input("""Enter the symbol of the operation to be performed. Your choices are:
                                             +
                                             - (Difference)
                                             *
                                             /
\n """))


if operation == "-" :
    sub1 = num1-num2
    sub2 = num2 - num1
    if num1 > num2:
        print(sub1)
    else:
        print(sub2)

elif operation == "+" :
    add = num1+num2
    print(add)

elif operation == "*" :
    product = num1*num2
    print(product)

elif operation == "/" :
    if num2 == 0:
        print("Sorry, can't divide a number by zero")
    else:
        quotient = num1 / num2
        print(quotient)

else:
    print("Please enter a valid operator from among the ones provided above")
```

This part is just a suggestion. You could also make your Difference operation easier by using the following.

```
if operation == "-" :
    sub1 = num1-num2
    print(abs(sub1))
```

`abs` gets the absolute value, basically removes the negative.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now that performing calculations for all operations beforehand is redundant.

Comment: Could you also clarify as to why python doesn't take the: if num2 == 0  statement into account for division by zero?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @blackdotso It does take it into account. But in your code, you were already dividing by zero at the line `quotient = num1 / num2` and that's why it was giving you the error

Comment: How your code is currently set up, it never even makes it to that statement.

Comment: @Abhishek Understood! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Find the quotient inside the `if` condition, not before checking `num==0`, otherwise the division by `zero` is already done, causing the error.:

```
elif operation == "/" :
    if num2 == 0:
        print("Sorry, can't divide a number by zero")
    else:
        quotient = num1 / num2
        print(quotient)
```

Comment: I think you want it in the `else` block, not in the `if` where it will always raise an exception.

Comment: Definitely needs to be in the else block

Answer (score 1):

```
quotient = num1 / num2
```

That's the line that is giving you the error. You should be checking if num2 is zero before calculating `num1 / num2`. You can do it as follows and your program would work fine.

```
quotient
if num2 == 0:
    quotient = None
else :
    quotient = num1 / num2
```

Else you could just declare quotient and calculate the quotient when user inputs the operator. If user enters `/`, then you can check if `num2==0` and if it is you can give error message.

### Working code -

```
print("Welcome to the calculator \n")

num1 = int(input("Enter the first number \n"))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number \n"))

operation = (input("""Enter the symbol of the operation to be performed. Your choices are:
                                             +
                                             - (Difference)
                                             *
                                             /
\n """))

add = num1+num2

sub1 = num1-num2
sub2 = num2 - num1

product = num1*num2
quotient = None     # Don't divide by num2 here or you will get error of divisionbyzero

if operation == "-" :

    if num1 > num2:
        print(sub1)
    else:
        print(sub2)

elif operation == "+" :
    print(add)

elif operation == "*" :
    print(product)

elif operation == "/" :
    if num2 == 0:
        print("Sorry, can't divide a number by zero")
    else:
        quotient = num1 / num2
        print(quotient)

else:
    print("Please enter a valid operator from among the ones provided above")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the results only after checking the operators (thus avoiding any errors caused by trying to divide by zero), this way you will also avoid unnecessary calculations:

```
elif operation == "/" :
    if num2 == 0: 
        print("Sorry, can't divide a number by zero")
    else:
        quotient = num1 / num2
        print(quotient)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify as to why i seem to get an error with only the division part if the calculation was done before checking the operators?

Comment: Because you can perform all the other operations (add, subtract, multiply), but dividing by 0 is an invalid operation.